# Center align a view vertically to other (sibling) view iOS

Tags: ios, user-interface, autolayout, interface-builder, size-classes

i am working on an iOS project and want my 2 views to be vertically aligned with respect to each other as shown in attached image. 
There is an image view on left and a view on right side. The right side view contains some labels in it. I  am using **autolayouts** and have properly applied constraints to image view (i.e. top/leading/height/width).

Now i want my right view to be **center aligned (vertically)** to thumbnail but when i do this, it asks for *missing constraint **y position***. I don't know how to fix that (i can not add top/bottom constraint as my title label can have *1 or 2 lined* text and the *right side view will grow accordingly*)

Is it possible to achieve this? if yes, then how? Thanks.

## [image]

It's a tableView basically. Above image is for detailed description. Whereas, design should be like the following (right side view should be centered aligned to left side image)

[image]

Comment: if you're down voting, then kindly mention the reason as well

Comment: I'm not sure what you need exactly. There are to many rectangles in your screenshot. Can you create a simpler version? Or add a screenshot from the storyboard.

Comment: it was supposed to be a tableview cell. Please see the bottom one. there's an image view and a rightSide view. The right side view should be center aligned to the image view. @Stefan

Comment: and ignore the right rectangle (grey one). It's just supposed to explain the stuff. Please check the left one (white rect) only

Comment: Well you might be getting missing constraints as you might have not give top or bottom to right view. You view will require height or top and bottom constraint to both you views with priority. So that height of image view remains fixed and if data in Title label increases then you can increase height of right view and of cell.